# CSS fading multiple images. Delaying opacity transition. Webkit transition delay

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, fadein, opacity

I am trying to fade in 3 images stacked on top of one another. Using just CSS transitions.

Here is my codepen:

http://codepen.io/FredHair/pen/MYQZJv?editors=110

I have managed to fade into the first image but am unsure how to correctly delay and fade into the third image.

I have found alot of questions on here similar to this but none of them helped me decipher exact code needed to achieve this.

My code:

HTML

```
<body>
 <div id="fadeImage">
<img id="image1" src="http://testdigits.com/wp-   content/uploads/2015/02/OpacAnimFrame1.png" alt="OpacAnimFrame1" >
<img id="image2" src="http://testdigits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/OpacAnimFrame2.png" alt="OpacAnimFrame2" >
<img id="image3" src="http://testdigits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/OpacAnimFrame3.png" alt="OpacAnimFrame3" >
</div>
```

CSS

```
#image1{
position: absolute;
left: 200px;
z-index: 3;
}

#image2{
 position: absolute;
 left: 200px;
z-index: 2;
}

#image3{
position: absolute;
left: 200px;
z-index: 1;
}

#image1:hover{
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
-o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
-ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
opacity: 0;
transition-delay:1s;
}

#image2:hover {
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
-o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
-ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
opacity: 0;
transition-delay:3s;
}
}
```

I would like to achieve this preferably only using CSS but if you know an easy jQuery fix I would also like to see that as well.

Thankyou for any help

MrB

Comment: It's not clear what the effect should be **but** you should be aware that you can only hover the top image because the others are "obscured" by that top image. You might be better off placing the effect (whatever it is) when the container is hovered.

Comment: Thankyou I did not know that. I think CSS is probably not the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set the `:hover` on `#fadeImage` instead of the individual images. Here's my solution:

```css
#fadeImage {
  position: relative;
}

#fadeImage img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

#image1 {
  z-index: 3;
}

#image2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

#image3 {
  z-index: 1;
}

#fadeImage:hover #image1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#fadeImage:hover #image2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="fadeImage">
  <img id="image1" src="http://testdigits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/OpacAnimFrame1.png" alt="OpacAnimFrame1" >
  <img id="image2" src="http://testdigits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/OpacAnimFrame2.png" alt="OpacAnimFrame2" >
  <img id="image3" src="http://testdigits.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/OpacAnimFrame3.png" alt="OpacAnimFrame3" >
</div>
```